# Evaluating the maximum and minimum value but why is it showing incorrect values?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Java Program for giving five integers and then printing the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers.

When i calculate the sum in all the five ways and then comparing the values then it doesn't print the maximum and minimum values of the sum and instead of that it prints 10 and 0 as output.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class MiniMaxSum {

    static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
        int sum=0,compare=0,maximum=0,minimum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
                if(i!=j)
                {
                    //for calculating sum.
                    sum+=arr[j];
                }
            }
            compare=sum;
           //for finding the maximum and minimum value of sum 
            if(compare>sum)
                maximum=compare;
            else
                minimum=compare;

            sum=0;//assigning sum to 0 for calculating sum
        }
        //for printing the maximum and minimum values of sum of the
         array elements.
        System.out.println(maximum);
        System.out.println(minimum);
    }

    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[5];

         //giving inputs in the array
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            arr[i]= scan.nextInt();
        }
       // calling miniMaxSum method 
        miniMaxSum(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the input array values?

Comment: also `compare=sum;
            if(compare>sum)` - how could that be?

Comment: You do `compare=sum;` and then you check `if(compare>sum)`. So you will always go on the `else` branch.

Comment: can you please give us some input data and what would be the resultant output. Your question is not that much clear

Answer (score 2):

Replace this code:

```
int sum=0,compare=0,maximum=0,minimum=0;

...

compare=sum;
//for finding the maximum and minimum value of sum 
if(compare>sum)
    maximum=compare;
else
    minimum=compare;
```

With this code:

```
int sum=0, maximum=Integer.MIN_VALUE, minimum=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

...

if (sum > maximum) {
    maximum = sum;
}
if (sum < minimum) {
    minimum = sum;
}
```

Comment: The second `if` can be an `else if`.

Comment: @Lutzi In the first iteration both will be true

Comment: @Lutzi the first number can be both a min and max

Comment: True, but it doesn't matter, it's not necessary to assign `0` to sum two times.

Comment: My bad, what I said do not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is just to [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) the array first, then to get the min loop from `0 to < array.length - 1` and for the max from `array.length - 1 to 1`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    min += arr[i];
}
for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    max += arr[i];
}
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
compare=sum;
if(compare>sum)
```

Your if will never be passed and maximum will be always zero and minimum will be the last sum calculated.

Why don't compare directly sum with maximum?

```
if(sum>maximum){ maximum = sum; }
```